# Connecting Azure VM with internal IP without virtual network?

Tags: networking, azure, ip

I have two Virtual Machines, which due to some historical reasons are under two different subscriptions. I am trying to find a way to connect them through internal IPs.

Normally for public virtual IP, I open the relevant port on Azure portal and than add an iptable rule like

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 198.1.1.1/32 --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
```

And then I can connect with the public IP. I do the same by replacing the public ip as above to the internal ip but it didn't work.

After some search it seems the normal way is to create a virtual network and add the two machines in it. But I got two questions:

1. Is there a way like the iptables rule like can achieve what I want without the need to setup virtual network?
2. Can one add non-azure machine, like an VPS, in the virtual network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

> Is there a way like the iptables rule like can achieve what I want
>   without the need to setup virtual network?

No. Not really. A possible workaround would be to still create an InputEndpoint (Endpoint from the Portal) for both the virtual machines. Then change your `iptables` rules for both public and private Addresses. But no guarantees it will work. Moreover, when not part of a Virtual Network, the internal IP Address of a VM is very likely to change sooner or later, especially on restart.

Q2:

> Can one add non-azure machine, like an VPS, in the virtual network?

Technically yes. You have to use either Site-to-Site VPN (GA) or a Point-to-Site VPN (Preview). You can read more on [Site-to-Site VPN here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/) and [Point to Site VPN here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/).